# Transparency option in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, transparency

Good day! Here I want transparent background in `tcolorbox`, when box comes inside the box or page color applied case. Here I used yellow color background box, so I required yellow background, I can't make second box color into transparent.  If any option is there to change the background color using `tcolorbox`. Please do the needful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shadows}

\newenvironment{Boxone}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!30,colbacklower=white,]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\newenvironment{Boxtwo}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,colbacklower=white]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}

\begin{Boxone}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\begin{Boxtwo}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\end{Boxtwo}
\end{Boxone}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `enhanced jigsaw` and `opacityback`, you can make the `tcolorbox` transparent. Btw I have no idea why you want to use `colbacklower` here...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shadows}

\newenvironment{Boxone}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!30]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\newenvironment{Boxtwo}{\begin{tcolorbox}[opacityback=0,enhanced jigsaw]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}

\begin{Boxone}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\begin{Boxtwo}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\end{Boxtwo}
\end{Boxone}

\begin{Boxtwo}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\end{Boxtwo}
\end{document}
```

#### Inside an yellow box:

[image]

#### Not inside anything:

[image]

---

However, you should not use (or at least I don't recommend you to use) `\newenvironment` to define a new `tcolorbox`. The package has a macro for it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shadows}
\newtcolorbox{Boxone}{colback=yellow!30}
\newtcolorbox{Boxtwo}{opacityback=0,enhanced jigsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{Boxone}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\begin{Boxtwo}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\end{Boxtwo}
\end{Boxone}

\begin{Boxtwo}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\end{Boxtwo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Joule for valuable, your answer exactly fulfill my requirement :).

Comment: @RajeshKumar Glad to hear that. However, please see my renewed answer. I made some notes to you.

Comment: Yeah I got it, surely I will follow the same in future style definition using tcolorbox